# GIT SVN refetch remote branch that was deleted locally

Tags: git, svn, version-control

In my SVN repository I have multi-level branches for instance:

```
- trunk
- tags
- branches
   |-b1
   |  |-b1-1
   |  |-b1-2
   |-b2
   |-b3
```

When I cloned the SVN to GIT, all *b1* sub branches got into *b1* branch because the branch configuration in git.config is:

```
branches = SRC/MyProject/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
```

So, I wanted to change the local copy of *b1* to *b1/b1-1* and *b1/b1-2*.
What I did, was first to add to the git.config another line:

```
branches = SRC/Cx-Sense/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
branches = SRC/Cx-Sense/branches/b1/*:refs/remotes/b1/*
```

I tried to `git svn fetch` but no changes were reflected, so what I did (wrongfully) was to delete *b1* from the local repository.

Now I have 2 problems:

1. I don't have *b1* (`git svn fetch` doesn't "refetch" it). How do I make git to refetch it?
2. How to get change *b1* to be fetched into *b1/b1-1* and *b1/b1-2*?

I should point out that I really want to avoid re-cloning the whole repository because (1) it is a big project, (2) I prefer to know how to fix it rather than just "restarting".

Thanks a lot for your help!!!